# Need xpath 1.0 to match an option with an id like "recipients-5342647-address"

Tags: php, xpath, xpath-1.0

I'm having trouble with the syntax for an xpath query in php that tries to match an html select element that has an id attribute in the following format:

```
recipients-1234567-address
```

The numeric part of the id will change and may not always be the same length. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
$select_el = 
   $xpath->query(".//select[@id[
                         starts-with(., 'recipients-')
                         AND
                         substring-before(substring(.,11),'-') = number(substring-before(substring(.,11),'-'))
                         AND
                         substring-after(substring-after(.,'-'),'-') = 'address' 
                         ]]");
```

I thought the prob might be with my node context, so I've also tried this variation...

```
$select_el = 
   $xpath->query(".//select[
                         starts-with(@id, 'recipients-')
                         AND
                         substring-before(substring(@id,11),'-') = number(substring-before(substring(@id,11),'-'))
                         AND
                         substring-after(substring-after(@id,'-'),'-') = 'address' 
                         ]");
```

This is my first time working with complicated xpath expressions, so I'm not sure if I'm way off base here or not. The xpath query must stick to valid xpath 1.0 syntax. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would try these tests for the last 2: `number(substring-before(substring-after(@id, 'recipients-'), '-address'))>0 and substring-after(substring-after(@id, 'recipients-'), '-')='address'`

Comment: Dude, you rule! Worked like a charm. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to try this:

```
//select[translate(@id,'0123456789','')='recipients--address']
```